# python:How to modify globals inside functions with schelude?

Tags: python

```
import time
import schedule

seconds = 0.01

def job():
    print("I'm working...")
    global seconds
    seconds += 0.01

schedule.every(seconds).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

It won't actually increase seconds every time it gets executed,sorry for the bad explanation was in a hurry

Comment: Please update your question with the reason that `The timer simply won't add numbers`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the line

```
seconds = 0.01
```

from your function. Every time this function is invoked, your variable `seconds` keeps getting re-initialised to `0.01`, thus not letting it increase any further. You have already initialised it once at the time of declaration, so don’t need to do it again and again.

```
def job():
    print("I'm working...")
    global seconds
    seconds += 0.01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
seconds = 0.01

def job():
    print("I'm working...")
    global seconds
    seconds += 0.01

schedule.every(seconds).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import schedule

seconds = 1

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(0.01).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    seconds += 1
    time.sleep(seconds)
```

This is one way of solving it....not really optimaly visual,but it works